# Getting 2 separate tkinter windows instead of navigating through 3 pages

Tags: python-3.x, csv, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to combine my graphs from matplot into the tkinter window and be able to navigate through the different graphs. I have tried experimenting for now and have one graph on it. However, I get 2 windows from tkinter instead of 1.

[image]

I've inserted the code I have done so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *
import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm


LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 12) #font type and font size

df1= pd.read_csv(r"U:\\GE90\nodes_fixed.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv(r"U:\\GE90\edge_list_3_fixed.csv")

g=nx.Graph()
# Add edges and edge attributes
for i, elrow in df2.iterrows():
# g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict())  # 
deprecated after NX 1.11
g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], **elrow[2:].to_dict())

app=Tk()

class Trial(tk.Tk):

#self -implied but does not need to be passed at all depending on the 
structure
#* = args   --> arguments, unlimited number of variables --> can pass 
through as many variables as you want
#** = kwargs --> keyboard arguments, passing through dictionaries 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Trial Only")
    container = tk.Frame(self)

    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, plot):

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
    button.pack()

#Adding a page

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to home",
                           command=lambda: 
controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()

    button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit page two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
    button2.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button3.pack()

    button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
    button4.pack()

    button5 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 3",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
    button5.pack()

class plot (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label= tl.Label(self, text= "Figure 1", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


# Edge list example
        print(elrow[0]) # node1
        print(elrow[1]) # node2
        print(elrow[2:].to_dict()) # edge attribute dict


# Add node attributes
for i, nlrow in df1.iterrows():
# g.node[nlrow['id']] = nlrow[1:].to_dict()  # deprecated after NX 1.11
nx.set_node_attributes(g, {nlrow['ID']:  nlrow[1:].to_dict()}) 

# Node list example
print(nlrow)

# Preview first 5 edges

list(g.edges(data=True))[0:5] 

# Preview first 10 nodes

list(g.nodes(data=True))[0:10] 

print('# of edges: {}'.format(g.number_of_edges()))
print('# of nodes: {}'.format(g.number_of_nodes()))

# Define node positions data structure (dict) for plotting
for node in g.nodes(data=True):
print(node)
print("")
node_positions = {node[0]: (node[1]['X'], -node[1]['Y']) for node in 
g.nodes(data=True)}

# Preview of node_positions
dict(list(node_positions.items())[0:5])

# Define data structure (list) of edge colors for plotting

# edge_colors = [e[2]['color'] for e in g.edges(data=True)]  
edge_colors = [e[2]['color'] for e in list(g.edges(data=True))]

# Preview first 10
edge_colors[0:10]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
nx.draw(g, pos=node_positions, edge_color=edge_colors, node_size=10, 
node_color='black')
plt.title('Graph Representation of repair trail', size=15)




canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, app)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()


app = Trial()
app.mainloop()
```

I want to display one window from tkinter to display all the different pages, however, the output gives me 2 different windows from tkinter
1st with all the starting pages and the buttons
2nd just with the graph from    class plot

Comment: You create a first window with `app=Tk()`, then a second one when you init `Trial` because it inherits from `Tk`. I think you can just remove the line  `app=Tk()` since you override it later with `app = Trial()`. BTW there are indentation issues in your code and you have posted more code than necessary for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @j_4321 My apologies for the messy coding and too much code being posted. I am new coding and being in stack overflow. 

I would like to ask further about replacing app=Tk() with app=Trial(). I have just tried it on my code and it gave me an error NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: Then please fix the indentation in the question. Since you have an error, this means that you are using `app` before `app = Trial()`. Either you want `Trial` to be the root window, and in this case, create it before `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, app)` or you don't and in this case make `Trial` inherit from `Frame` and pack it in app.

Comment: @j_4321 I have done this and it did combine both, however, I cannot navigate away from the plot and it shows despite clicking through to different pages

Comment: You need to create the plot in one of the pages: create `Trial` first, then  create your  graph with `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, <master>)` replacing master by your PageOne for instance (the one stored in `app.frames`). It seems like you are trying to put together pieces of code you don't understand, so I would advise you to take the time to analyze each piece of code separately and have a look at simple examples of OOP with tkinter first.

Comment: @j_4321 I will try that and I will do that further. I have watched a tutorial on youtube about integrating matlab plots in tkinter but I got confused as they entered values themselves and didn't fully understand how to do it for this specific code. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two windows because you create a first window with `app = Tk()`, then a second one when you init `Trial` because it inherits from `Tk`. In fact you don't need `app = Tk()`.

You want your plot to be in one of the pages, so you need to move all the code creating the matplotlib figure inside one of your `Page` class, e.g. `PageTwo`:

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # code for the plot
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))  # create matplotlib figure
        # add axes and plot (replace this by your matplotlib code)
        ax = fig.subplots() 
        ax.plot(range(10))
        ax.set_title('Graph Representation of repair trail', size=15)
        # create the tkinter widget to display the figure
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)  # here self is the widget in which you want to display the figure
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)  # add toolbar
        canvas.draw()  # show content

        # navigation button 
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button4.pack()
```

Comment: Could I possible ask what "canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()" does? what is .get_tk_widget?

Comment: @ElizabethDC `canvas.get_tk_widget()` returns the tkinter widget containing the matplotlib figure. `pack` is the method used to display this widget in the page, you could also use `grid` or `place` instead.

Comment: I have replaced the code to this: 
`fig = Figure()
        canvas= plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
        nx.draw(g, pos=node_positions, edge_color=edge_colors, node_size=10, node_color='black')
        plt.title('Graph Representation of repair trail', size=15)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        canvas.draw()'`
Please do correct me if I am wrong, but fig=Figure() provides a blank canvas? 
I have tried this but :
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bbox'`
I am not sure where bbox is coming from?

Comment: According to the code you posted, you should have `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))` and `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)`. Not `canvas= plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))` because `canvas` is the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` containing the figure, not the matplotlib figure.

Comment: That makes sense to me, however,I don't understand why I now get an error that `NameError: name 'fig' is not defined` ? 
we have defined fig to be `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))`? so why does this return fig is not defined?
I have just moved all the other code for the calculations on the top of the code, would this have affected it?

Comment: You probably use `fig` somewhere else in your code, either outside the `PageTwo` class (in this case move this piece of code inside the class) or before `fig = ...` in the class (then move it after).

Comment: I have tried that but now I am getting an error saying `name 'self' is not defined` I watched a video and all it mentioned was self is implied but does not need to be passed at all depending on the structure. What does it mean when it says that `self` is not defined? and what actually is `self`?

Comment: If you are asking this question then you need to read a tuto about object oriented programming. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have now fixed it and managed to get it into a page as I have wanted

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly creating two windows.

The first is this line: `app=Tk()`

The second is the line `app = Trial()`, since `Trial` inherits from `tk.Tk`.

Comment: If I move app=Trial() above the canvas lines, it does combine them together but I cannot change pages away from the figure